# Unsupported image type with fpdf

Tags: php, iphone, image, jpeg, fpdf

i have this message error:

> Unsupported image type:imagePath was not found on this server.

I want to create pdf with jpg images taken from the iphone. Unfortunately this does not work. The image path is just seen that I can access it from my browser. When I change the way the path is erroneous.

A exemple of the code

```
$pdf->Image('../firstParthPath/'.$_SESSION['environment'].'/secondParthPath'.$ImageName,null,$heigth,40,50);
```

`$ImageName` are `/image404-120404.jpg` for exemple. I have tested variable name. It has `/image404-120404.jpg`

`$heigth` is a variable that is also handled automatically. It always has the desired content.

I tried to replace null with 0

I tried to add the option 'JPG'. Without success.

a exemple of image 
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/72/image398120404.jpg/

Comment: you can try to pre manipulate the image with imagemagick using the "convert" command.

Comment: the image are automatically generate to iPhone

Comment: yes. i know. but you can "process" them on your server first (before placing them with fpdf) by using convert of the imagemagick library.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that PHP is not understanding the location via the relative path starting with '../'. You could try explicitly prepending the script path before it to make sure PHP is looking in the correct place:

```
(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../firstParthPath/'.$_SESSION['environment'].'/secondParthPath'.$ImageName,null,$heigth,40,50);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's resolved. It was a verification error in the next picture. Now the problem's are resolved